# Redirect http to https on Beanstalk's ALB without support of https on the instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I have the following beanstalk environment: https(443) -> ALB -> http(80) to instance.
ALB listener accept only HTTPS request and authenticate with SSL certificate and then process to default port 80.

Everything works fine but I wonder if is it also possible to redirect HTTP port 80 requests back to ALB HTTPS listener without the need to support HTTPS on the instance?
When I tried to create redirect process it failed since it tried health-check on port 443 and the instance doesn't support it.

P.S. Is it a security issue if authentication done only in ALB and it communicate instances on port 80? (Instance security group accept requests only from ALB)

Comment: Hi. I've noticed that you have bunch of questions with answers, but not a single one was accepted. It is a good practice to accept questions which were helpful as it also can help others in future and signals to people who answer that a given issues was solved.

Comment: ok, I wasn't aware of accept, I'll try to use it from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redirection from port HTTP to HTTPS is best set using EC2 console, not EB console. For that you have to go to EC2 console-> Load Balancers.

Then you can modify the existing rule on HTTP:80 listener from `Forward` to `Redirect` as shown below:

[image]

The above change should not affect any of your health checks.

> Is it a security issue if authentication done only in ALB and it communicate instances on port 80?

Yes. This is how it is most commonly done. The HTTP traffic between ALB and your instances traverses only AWS network, not the internet. So its safe from public eyes. But obviously, you can still setup HTTPS between ALB and the instances, but this requires extra work and puts more stress on your instances as they now have to handle SSL encryption and decryption as well.

Comment: Thanks, when I do it on ec2 console it doesn't reflect on the EB console since EB console doesn't show the action type (forward/redirect) so is there a risk that after changing EB configuration, deployment new war or other action EB will overwrite the action back to forward?

Comment: @user3369398 No problem. Not that I'm aware of. Deployment of new application  shouldn't have impact on your ALB. But this is something you can easily be check. Just deploy a new version for test and observe if there are any changes on your ALB.